# Can i use zip.js in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, zip

I am using phonegap+sencha touch 2 to develop android app.
Now i want to zip the images into a folder . And send to the server.

It is working in google chrome,mozilla-firefox and all web browsers.
But in phonegap it is giving error for blob. That is `illegal constructor`.
Is zip.js working in phonegap??
Or is any other method to zip the images in phonegap??