# Unzip files using zip.js in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, zip

I am using phonegap to develop android app, and also need to unzip files(including .png and .txt files) from SD card.

using zip.js can read the zip file structure from SD card,like file/directory list, but when i try to inflate zip file and obtain the file content, it is giving illegal constructor error.

I have tried many times,but without success. How can I do this?

```
function readZip3()
{
    var fullPath = $('#dir_path').val() + "/" + "2151849.zip";
    fs.root.getFile(fullPath, {}, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {

            var dateBefore = new Date();

            zip.createReader(new zip.BlobReader(file), function (zipReader) {
                zipReader.getEntries(function (entries) {   
                    alert(entries[28].filename);                        
                    entries[28].getData(new zip.BlobWriter(), function (data) {

                        alert(data);
                        $('#result').append(data);

                        zipReader.close(function () {

                        });
                    }, function(current, total) {
                        // onprogress callback
                    });

                });
            }, onerror);

            var dateAfter = new Date();
            $('#time').html(" (parsed in " + (dateAfter - dateBefore) + "ms)");

        }, errorHandler);
    }, errorHandler);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: sure, the entries[28] is a text file.
alert(entries[28].filename) can print the filename successfully

Comment: Hi @Roger how did you fix the error in the end?

Comment: hi @James Wong, I use the plug-in finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a PR to fix that issue: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/pull/70

Dupe here : [Can i use zip.js in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509840/can-i-use-zip-js-in-phonegap/18232294#18232294)

Comment: I've tried the new zip.js.
this time it's not giving illegal constructor error, but print 
"Unknow chromium error:-6" in Eclipse.
Ps:I am using phonegap v2.9